# How to add data dynamically to drilldown maps?

Tags: highcharts

Here I am again, with another Highmaps query….  I’m getting there with it all, but… I want now to use the drilldown feature to bring up a custom “sub-map”, and onto that I want to add – dynamically – a number of point-locations )eg towns within a region) at specified point sn the map, which will show relevant data in the tooltip on rollover...

The js fiddle below shows the basic idea, though the drilldown “data” is clearly not what is required ... somehow each drilldown must show the relevant map outline (not the same one used here for each) and then somewhere I need to add the locations, their position on the map, and some data for each.

I don’t expect anyone to be able to use this to create a working fiddle, but if you could just point me in the right direction I’d be grateful – I’m sure I can get there in the end if nudged…

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/philu/8v7xbLoy/5/

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        "lang": {"drillUpText": "&lt; Back to U.K. map"},
     });
     $('#container').highcharts("Map", {
        "title": {
           "text": "UK"
        },
        "series": [
            {
              "name": "Today",
                "type": "map",
                "tooltip": {
                   "pointFormat": "{point.name}"
                },
                "dataLabels": {
                   "enabled": true,
                   "useHTML": true,
                   "color": '#FFFFFF',
                   "formatter": function () {
                      return this.point.name + '<br>Some data...'
                   }
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                          "color": "#ffcccc",
                       "drilldown": "England",
                       "name": "England",
                        "path": "M0,-994L204,-994L203,-480,0,-477z"
                    },
                    {
                       "color": "#ccffcc",
                       "drilldown": "Wales",
                       "name": "Wales7",
                        "path": "M204,-994L455,-994L457,-477,203,-480z"
                    }
                ]   
            }
        ],
        "drilldown": {
            "series": [
            {
               "id": "England",
               "name": "England",
               "type": "map",
               "tooltip": {
                  "headerFormat": "",
                  "pointFormat": "{point.name}"
               },
               "data": [
                  {
                     "name": "path4550",
                     "path": "M0,-861,2,-514,400,-292,560,-388,885,-203,1000,-627,651,-827,610,-977,234,-802Z"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id": "Wales",
               "name": "Wales",
               "type": "map",
               "tooltip": {
                  "headerFormat": "",
                  "pointFormat": "{point.name}"
               },
               "data": [
                  {
                     "name": "path4550",
                     "path": "M0,-861,2,-514,400,-292,560,-388,885,-203,1000,-627,651,-827,610,-977,234,-802Z"
                  }
               ]
            }
           ]
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom drilldown and add a `map` and a `mappoint` series types:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
            if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                var chart = this,
                    drilldowns = {
                        'England': {...},
                        'England-points': {
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            data: [{
                                name: 'London',
                                x: 150,
                                y: -500
                            }, {
                                name: 'Birmingham',
                                x: 500,
                                y: -600
                            }]
                        },
                        'Wales': {...},
                        'Wales-points': {
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            data: [{
                                name: 'London',
                                x: 150,
                                y: -500
                            }, {
                                name: 'Birmingham',
                                x: 500,
                                y: -600
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    series = drilldowns[e.point.name],
                    series2 = drilldowns[e.point.name + '-points'];

                chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series2);
                chart.applyDrilldown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bpq128jw/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.events.drilldown

Comment: Thanks - brilliant. One other question, if I may:  can I prevent the rollover effect on the drilldown maps, except on the actual points (of course)?  I tried setting  tooltips.enabled = false, but that doesn't seem to do it....

Comment: Yeah, why would it? :) Actually, just changing the drilldown series type from map to mapline is better, but there is stlll a rollover effect that pretty much hides the underlying map/outline....

Comment: Hi @PSU, Please try to use `hover` and `inactive` series states: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zpa5L2jc/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek - ok, one last thing, and I promise to leave you alone :)  On the drilldown, moving the mouse over the area NOT on a data point, I see the (useless) tooltip showing "path4550" - the data.name . For the life of me I can't get rid of it... how? Why not tooltip.enabled = false?

Comment: Hi @PSU, Please feel free to ask. You can disable the `enableMouseTracking` option for `map` series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gocda8eq/

Comment: Thanks - incidentally, I was trying to look up your addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown in the API docs, but could only find a reference to addSeriesAsDrilldown - I presume yours is new and the API docs not updated... is it different in some way, and if so, how?

Comment: You can check the `drilldown` module source code: https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.src.js The `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` method is internal, but it allows to create a multiple series drilldown. Also, it requires to use the `applyDrilldown` method. The `addSeriesAsDrilldown` is independent, but it allows to add only one drilldown series.